# Selection of character vector elements containing regex from using purrr and stringr

Tags: r, regex, tidyverse, purrr, stringr

I have a list of character vectors and I want to keep only those elements of the vectors that contains specific regex. Unfortunately I was not able to convince purrr to feed the vectors to stringr.
General aim of my effort is extract sentences with regex from text in one column of a tibble and concatenate them to another column.
Do somebody has a purrre tidyverse solution? Thanks for any help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This prototype solution works :) Not sure why it did not work the first time though ;) Still will be glad for your comments.

```
# Prototype solution ----
library(purrr)
library(stringr)
pr_pattern <- "rr" 
pr_db <- list(
  A = c("Apples and oranges.", "Oranges and cherries.", "Nuts and grapes."), 
  B = c("Oranges and apples.", "Cherries and oranges.", "Grapes and nuts.")
  )
pr_res <- map(pr_db, ~ str_subset(.x, pr_pattern))
```